# Numba slowing Code?

Tags: python, performance, numba

I was impressed by the speedup that was gained [HERE](http://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2013/06/15/numba-vs-cython-take-2/) by using `numba`

Today I found in SO a [question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/45857/count-distinct-primes-discarding-palindromes-in-under-2-seconds) from someone who is looking to speedup his code. So I thought let' s have a look what we can achieve with `numba`.

Here is the code:

```
from numba import autojit
from time import time

LIMIT = pow(10,6)

def primes(limit):
    # Keep only odd numbers in sieve, mapping from index to number is
    # num = 2 * idx + 3
    # The square of the number corresponding to idx then corresponds to:
    # idx2 = 2*idx*idx + 6*idx + 3
    sieve = [True] * (limit // 2)
    prime_numbers = set([2])
    for j in range(len(sieve)):
        if sieve[j]:
            new_prime = 2*j + 3
            prime_numbers.add(new_prime)
            for k in range((2*j+6)*j+3, len(sieve), new_prime):
                sieve[k] = False
    return list(prime_numbers)


numba_primes = autojit(primes)



start = time()
numba_primes(LIMIT)
end=time()
print("Numba: Time Taken : ",end-start)

start = time()
primes(LIMIT)
end=time()
print("Python: Time Taken : ",end-start)
```

The result:

```
('Numba: Time Taken : ', 0.68790602684021)
('Python: Time Taken : ', 0.12417221069335938)
```

Why is this happening? It seems that with `numba` this piece of code is not getting any faster!

Comment: First question - what version of Numba are you using. There was a major refactoring between 0.11 and 0.12 that changed how things behaved dramatically with a number of performance/feature regressions.

Comment: Also, Numba does not speed-up arbitrary python code. It does wonders on for-loops crunching numpy arrays. You won't expect to see much performance for manipulation of python objects. Notice that your problem and Jake's are totally different in that regard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a numba-ized version (using Numba 0.13) of your code this is optimized by using numpy arrays

```
import numpy as np
import numba

# You could also just use @numba.jit or @numba.jit(nopython=True)
# here and get comparable timings.
@numba.jit('void(uint8[:])', nopython=True)
def primes_util(sieve):
    ssz = sieve.shape[0]
    for j in xrange(ssz):
        if sieve[j]:
            new_prime = 2*j + 3
            for k in xrange((2*j+6)*j+3, ssz, new_prime):
                sieve[k] = False

def primes_numba(limit):
    sieve = np.ones(limit // 2, dtype=np.uint8)
    primes_util(sieve)

    return [2] + (np.nonzero(sieve)[0]*2 + 3).tolist()
```

and then a comparison with timings:

```
In [112]: %timeit primes(LIMIT)
1 loops, best of 3: 221 ms per loop

In [113]: %timeit primes_numba(LIMIT)
100 loops, best of 3: 11 ms per loop

In [114]:

a = set(primes(LIMIT))
b = set(primes_numba(LIMIT))

a == b
Out[114]:

True
```

That's a 20x speedup, although there are probably even further optimization that could be made. Without the jit decorator, the numba version runs in about 300 ms on my machine. The actual call to `primes_util` only takes about 5 ms and the rest is the call to `np.nonzero` and the conversion to a list.

Comment: I use numba 0.13. Yes you are right. It seems that numba gets the most of it when working with arrays. In your code you wanted to write np.nonzero(sieve) without x